# Xcode 13.4.1 error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database (react native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

```
**error** Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening app.xcworkspace.

**error**: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-cdawdoxdzwfdgueqnyshuhonxndw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.
```

tried almost everything
build cleans, reinstalling pods etc

react native version: 0.67.3
Xcode version: 13.4.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After almost one day of debugging this issue, came to know about this article which solves the problem for me, although article has more than one steps but I just tried the last one and it worked, mentioning the steps below,

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod update
cd..
yarn run ios or npm run ios
```

Comment: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/  was giving me permission denied error so i skipped it and used the other commands and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I *only* did the "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/" and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a long time to find a solution to the problem. The method suggested by another user makes sense, but for some reason it didn't work for me. This error occurs because some process is accessing the database created by XCode in parallel during startup; it cannot process 2 requests at once. What can you do if the user's solution did not help:

1. Go to your YourProjectName.xcworkspace -> Product->CleanBuildFolder - this will clear your project cache
2. Go to the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ folder and delete everything in it, reinstall the pods.
3. Close everything on your device, then turn it off (do not reboot, but turn it off by unchecking the “*open applications after startup*” option)